# How do I write lines to a text file easily if I have a dictionary with the key of the line and contents being the text?

Tags: python

If there's a smarter/easier way to do this I'd be very glad to know. My knowledge of file-handling is very basic so I'm in uncharted waters right now.

The code in question:

```
fileBin = open("HarryPotterBooks.txt", "r")
fileKeys = open("HarryPotterBooks.txt", "r")

binValues = list(list(map(lambda x: bin(ord(x)), line)) for line in fileBin)

keys = list(
    x for x in range(len([line.strip("\n") for line in fileKeys if line != "\n"]))
)

res = dict(zip(keys, binValues))

fileBin.close()
fileKeys.close()


newFile = open("BinaryConverted.txt", "w")

# Writing to the file
```

Answer (score 1):

its better to use `with open` instead of `open` and `close`

```
with open(file_name, "r") as f:
    #do what you want, close automatically
```

Comment: Ah true, completely forgot about that thanks. Any idea on the writing bit with the dictionary?